# How to change number format in power editor?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, m

A cell value is `858497.997359999` but what I see in power query is `858497`. The Excel custom number format is `_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`
How can i see the whole number in power query? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you have provided. Please edit your question to provide sufficient information **after reading** the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the number format but to see the actual value in PQ, just click on the cell.

[image]